# Why am I seeing an error on -setAppUUID: on iOS when developing for the Pebble watch?

Tags: ios, iphone, pebble-watch

I wanted to create an iOS app for the Pebble watch, but I'm running into a problem with their sample code.

When I use the following code

```
uuid_t myAppUUIDbytes;
NSUUID *myAppUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"226834ae-786e-4302-a52f-6e7efc9f990b"];
[myAppUUID getUUIDBytes:myAppUUIDbytes];

[[PBPebbleCentral defaultCentral] setAppUUID:[NSData dataWithBytes:myAppUUIDbytes length:16]];
```

I'm seeing the error

```
**setAppUUID** No visible @interface for 'PBPebbleCentral' declares the selector 'setAppUUID'
```

Why am I seeing this error, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the following frameworks to remove this error:

```
PebbleKit.framework
PebbleVendir.framework
```